# sql server pivot multiple fields by two columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm given a messy "fact" table in SQL Server 2012 with OrderId and ProductId being the keys. The same OrderId can have multiple ProductId (up to 5 rows). For reporting purposes I need to leave only one row for each combination OrderId+ProductId, using the max value from the 5 fields Ask, Buy, Rec, Pen, Ret.

I've tried using the pivot operator over ProductId, but don't know how to get the max value from the 5 different fields.

Sample data:

```
DROP TABLE #tmpSO;

CREATE TABLE #tmpSO
(OrderId INT, ProductId INT, Ask INT, Buy INT, Rec INT, Pen INT, Ret INT);

INSERT INTO #tmpSO (OrderId, ProductId, Ask, Buy, Rec, Pen, Ret)
VALUES
(67,1,2,0,0,2,0),
(67,4,30,0,0,30,0),
(67,4,0,30,0,30,0),
(67,6,20,0,0,0,0),
(67,6,0,20,0,0,0),
(67,6,0,0,20,0,0),
(67,9,30,0,0,0,0),
(67,9,0,30,0,0,0),
(67,9,0,0,25,0,0),
(67,9,0,0,0,5,0);

SELECT * FROM #tmpSO;

OrderId ProductId   Ask Buy Rec Pen Ret
67      1           2   0   0   2   0
67      4           30  0   0   30  0
67      4           0   30  0   30  0
67      6           20  0   0   0   0
67      6           0   20  0   0   0
67      6           0   0   20  0   0
67      9           30  0   0   0   0
67      9           0   30  0   0   0
67      9           0   0   25  0   0
67      9           0   0   0   5   0
```

My desired result would be:

```
OrderId ProductId   Ask Buy Rec Pen Ret
67      1           2   0   0   2   0
67      4           30  30  0   30  0
67      6           20  20  20  0   0
67      9           30  30  25  5   0
```

Please advise if this is feasible using Pivot (or other operator), and a help showing how to use it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`?

It would give your expected result:

```
select orderid, productid, MAX(ask) ask, MAX(buy) as buy, MAX(rec) as rec, MAX(pen) as pen, MAX(ret) as ret
from #tmpso 
group by orderid, productid
order by orderid, productid
```

Working copy [here](http://rextester.com/CITD70565).

Comment: Thanks, thing is, I didn't specify in question, but these fact tables are real messy, they make one per month and the number of columns is variable, some have 48, some 50 etc. Only the columns showed here are always present. So I'm trying to make a generic solution to consolidate the values I'm interested in and avoid grouping by 40, 41, 42 fields.

Comment: It sounds like you need to build your query dynamically? If so, the same logic would still apply. Are you looking for answers on how to build the dynamic query?

Comment: Ok, I think that dynamically is not possible because I don't know beforehand what the column names are. But I can use your suggestion to build a temp table with only the values I'm interested in. And then inner join it with the main table.